# How to generate root-level links in ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

An ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application has the following route rules:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "blog_list_year_month_paged",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Blog", 
        action = "Index", 
        page = (int?)null,
    },
    template: "blog/{year}/{month}/page/{page}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "blog_post",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Blog", 
        action = "BlogPost" 
    },
    template: "blog/{year}/{month}/{codename}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "blog_list_year_month",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Blog", 
        action = "Index", 
        year = (int?)null, 
        month = (int?)null,
        page = (int?)null,
    },
    template: "blog/{year?}/{month?}");
```

The master page has the following link:

```
<a asp-controller="Blog" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
```

The link reuses the values of the `year`, `month` and `page` variables of the current page. For example, if the current page is a home page, the route generates a link respecting that the current `page` value is `/Index` as the home page is a Razor page called Index (located in a /Pages folder). If the current page is a specific blog post, the generated url is `/blog/2018/2/blog-post-title`.

How to effectively express that the link is supposed to be a root link, i.e. it should always result in a `/blog` url?

I have come up with expressively setting all possible variables to `null` (via `asp-route-month` etc.) but I do not consider this as a nice solution. I am also aware I might be able use the route name but I would prefer to keep them out in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For one option to generate the root URL, try to create the `tag a` with href directly like below:

```
<li><a href="/Blog">Blog</a></li>
```

For another option which is similiar like your current workaround, try to define empty route values and pass it like below:

```
@{
    var NullRoute = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "year", null } };
}

 <li><a asp-controller="Blog" asp-all-route-data="@NullRoute" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
```

Or, you could try [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to create your own tag helper to generate the expected html content.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. If I understand you correctly, you are not aware of any way how to elegantly tell ASP.NET to forget about the current page's context when generating an url for a route.

Comment: What is your `expected elegantly`? This is not related with `page's context`. If you press F12 to check the generted URL for `<a asp-controller="Blog" class="nav-link">Blog</a>`, it already converted to `blog/2` if your current URL is `blog/2`.

Comment: Yes, it is converted to `blog/2` because the current page's context has its `page` route variable set to `2`. I want to express that this link should not inherit the current page's `page` value (nor other values). Similarly, as current page's query parameters are not inherited if I would written `href="/blog"`.